# How to prevent custom dialog from popping twice in asynctask onPostExecute?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, customdialog

I'm using a custom dialog in onpostexecute method in AsyncTask, it is being popped twice. When the user clicks on a button the dialog has to be closed, this seems to work fine.

Can someone shed some light on why it is being called twice ?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    try {
        if (responseFromServer.contains("x")) {
            // Pop up to create password
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_password);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);

            final TextView etpassword = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etpassword_dialog);
            final Button btnpassword = (Button) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnsavepassword_dialog);

            btnpassword.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (etpassword.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    } else if (etpassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Password should contain minimmum 6 characters",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }
            });

            if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.show();
            }

        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unexpected error occurred. Please try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Main FRagment FB async::::::", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying that onPostExecute is being called twice for the same task? Or that the dialog is mysteriously popping up two times?  (Sequentially - one right after the first is dismissed, or both together?)  Or is it possible that you have multiple tasks that could potentially run in parallel?  I suspect that while your dialog is visible (and pumping messages), other tasks are completing and are invoking onPostExecute.  That's just a guess.

Comment: @user3121673 Are you trying to say that your `ProgressDialog` shows two times ? OR your `Custom Dialog` shown two times?

Comment: Are you working in Activity of fragment?

Comment: @Anirudh did u find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write following condition before display a custom dialog,

```
if ( !dialog.isShowing() )
{
   dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Try this, instead of declaring ` final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());` declare Dialog dialog at class level.

Comment: @user3121673 that is really a strange for me that it is not working.

Comment: @user3121673 You mean to say that when you click on button your dialog should be shown once only. And in your case its showing 2 times ?

Comment: @user3121673,hmmm lets see what others answer. I tried my way :)

Comment: @user3121673 Please post the whole code of your AsyncTask method.

Comment: I declared dialog at class level and checked null condition before instantiating the dialog, now its working fine. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @user3121673 you welcome. You may accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct there is no problem in code. Check button click. i think you are calling twice execute() method of AsyncTask.
Can you post the calling code like how are you calling AsyncTask fron button click.